# is it possible to SET an attribute value with XPath?

Tags: xpath, attributes

Is it possible to SET an attribute value with XPath, like this?

```
    XPathNavigator xNav = doc.CreateNavigator();
    xNav.MoveToAttribute("requestID", String.Empty);

    xNav.SetAttributeValue??  // need correct method to set a (new) value for current node-attribute..
```

Comment: for some reason it doesnt seem possible: the CanEdit field for the attribute is false...

i tried to remove the attribute from the xmldocument completely and tried to call 

xNav.CreateAttribute(string.Empty, "requestID", string.Empty, "TESTIDVALUE");

but that method is also not supported... surely the must be a way to add/edit atttributes with XPath??

Comment: There's no way to modify anything with XPath, but it should allow you to find the attribute nodes that you want to modify, so you can use some external API to do the modification; but that doesn't depend on XPath, it depends on the external API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably (in the code that you haven't shown), the XPathNavigator is constructed off an XPathDocument. An XPathDocument is read-only by definition (this is why it is much more efficient).

**From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.aspx)**:

> "*XPathNavigator objects created by XPathDocument objects are
>   read-only while XPathNavigator objects created by XmlDocument objects
>   can be edited.* "

If you want to update nodes using DOM, you must use another object -- say an XmlDocument.

Of course, people realized long (7 -8 years) ago that DOM isn't the best possible way of processing XML.

**I definitely recommend to do XML processing using XSLT -- a language especially designed for tree transformations**.